# VR speedrun timer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am working on a VR speedrun game and I need a timer. The timer doesn't need to be showed in the screen for the player, just on the map I made. It needs to start when the player (VR) passes a specific point and end when it reaches a different point. If anyone has an idea of how to make this work I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Turn it on when you want it on, `time += Time.deltaTime` while it's on. Not sure what else you're asking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the start line you could have an empty gameobject with a trigger collider on it, and in the OnTriggerEnter event you could start a Coroutine that keeps track of the time, and on the finish line you'd have another trigger collider that sets a flag and stops the timer.

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool _isTimerStarted = false;
    private float _timeElapsed = 0;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject.name.Equals("Start Line")) {
            _isTimerStarted = true;
            StartCoroutine(StartTimer());
        } else if (other.gameObject.name.Equals("Finish Line") {
            _isTimerStarted = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator StartTimer() {
        while (_isTimerStarted) {
            _elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

For this to work just make sure your player has a RigidBody attached or else no collision will be detected :)

Comment: Hi, thank you! This worked, I only had to make a few changes. At the start you assigned _timeElapsed but you never use that, and instead later you use _elapsedTime which was never assigned (I'm guessing you looked over this but incase someone also wants to use this)   
And at the top you also need to add  using System.Collections;
For the rest it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "timer" as in "show the elapsed time since some event" you might take a look at [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0)

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
...
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

The stopwatch is primarily intended for performance measurements. But it is easy to use, so if it fits your use case you might as well make use of it, even if the resolution and accuracy is much greater than you need.